# Getting 400 Bad Request while sending angularjs post request with objects

Tags: angularjs, spring-mvc

Ui code is

```
    var page1={"name":"raj","acc":"123"};
    var page2={"name1":"sathi","acc2":"321"};

    var finl={"page1":page1,"page2":page2};

    var response=$http.post("myfirsturl",{"page1":page1,"page2":page2});
```

spring controller code is

```
    @RequestMapping(value="/myfirsturl",method=RequestMethod.POST)
public String hello1(@RequestBody sampledetails details){

    page1 obj=details.getPag1();
    page2 obj2=details.getPag2();

    System.out.println(obj.getName()+"  "+obj.getAcc());
    System.out.println(obj2.getName1()+"  "+obj2.getAcc2());


    return "";
}
```

sampledetails class

```
  public class sampledetails implements Serializable{


  private page1 pag1;
   private page2 pag2;

   //setters and getters
```

page1 class

```
 public class page1 implements Serializable{

  private String name;
  private String acc;
  //setters and getters
```

page2 class
      public class page2 implements Serializable{

```
  private String name1;
  private String acc2;
  //setters and getters
```

I have tried sending object it is working for primitive types but not working for objects.

Comment: Is there any solution??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pag1 not page1 acccording to your sampledetails bean class. You must use member variable name.

**Change this**

```
var response=$http.post("myfirsturl",{"page1":page1,"page2":page2});
```

**To this**

```
var response=$http.post("myfirsturl",{"pag1":page1,"page2":pag2});
```

Or like this

```
$http.post('/myfirsturl', {         
            "pag1" : page1, "pag2" : page2
        }).success(function(data){
            alert("Success");
        })
```

Controller

```
@RestController
public class Controller {

     @RequestMapping(value="/myfirsturl",method=RequestMethod.POST)
     public String hello1(@RequestBody Sampledetails details){

         System.out.println("Inside");

         Page1 obj=details.getPag1();
         Page2 obj2=details.getPag2();

         System.out.println(obj.getName()+"  "+obj.getAcc());
         System.out.println(obj2.getName1()+"  "+obj2.getAcc2());


         return "";
     }

}
```